# Access to vpn hosts from inside Windows Docker Container

Tags: windows, docker, containers, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I have a Windows container running on **Docker Desktop** with a .Net framework project, the problem is when try to restore the packages, cannot find our internal artifactory.

I am connected via VPN to my company (Cisco AnyConnect) and have access to the artifactory repository, but the container has not. I know about the problems with windows containers and network interfaces (I had also this problems and need to move my connection from time to time https://improveandrepeat.com/2019/09/how-to-fix-network-errors-with-docker-and-windows-containers/)

I also added in the Docker settings the artifactory url to *emphasized text* (that works for Linux containers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar with Docker Desktop, i wrote the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66640222/1632288